# How to select max item per group from Flux

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Given the following `MyObject` and `Flux<MyObject>` what is the best way to remove `MyObjects` with same the same property from this flux?

```java
    import lombok.Data;
    import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
    
    public class Example {
    
        @Data
        public class MyObject {
            final String name;
            final int priority;
        }
    
        public Example() {
            Flux<MyObject> myFlux = Flux.just(
                    new MyObject("abc", 2),
                    new MyObject("abc", 4),
                    new MyObject("cde", 1));
        }
    }
```

For example I want to remove objects with same `name` while choosing the ones with higher `priority`.
Output: `[Example.MyObject(name=abc, priority=4), Example.MyObject(name=cde, priority=1)]`

If I use `myFlux.distinct(MyObject::getName)` I wont be able to choose which one to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `groupBy` and `reduce` operators on `Flux`:

```java
Flux.just(
        new MyObject("abc", 2),
        new MyObject("abc", 4),
        new MyObject("cde", 1))
    .groupBy(MyObject::getName)
    .flatMap(group -> group.reduce((o1, o2) -> o1.getPriority() > o2.getPriority() ? o1 : o2))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

One important consideration is that this only works well if the number of groups is small, otherwise it can result in a deadlock. As a remedy you can set the `maxConcurrency` parameter of `flatMap` to a higher value.

See [documentation of `groupBy` operator](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-):

> The groups need to be drained and consumed downstream for groupBy to
> work correctly. Notably when the criteria produces a large amount of
> groups, it can lead to hanging if the groups are not suitably consumed
> downstream (eg. due to a flatMap with a maxConcurrency parameter that
> is set too low).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you first need to convert this `Flux<MyObject>` into a `Mono<List<MyObject>>` because you need to know all objects and their priorities in order to sort them.

As soon as you have the list of all instances of `MyObject`, you can use the Java 8 Stream api to solve this:

```java
@Slf4j
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<MyObject> myFlux = Flux.just(
                        new MyObject("abc", 2),
                        new MyObject("abc", 4),
                        new MyObject("cde", 1))
                .collectList()
                .map(myObjectsList -> myObjectsList.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors
                                .groupingBy(MyObject::getName)))
                // now we have a Map<String, List<MyObject>>
                .map(Map::entrySet)
                // now we have a Set<Entry<String, List<MyObject>>>
                .flatMapIterable(entrySet -> entrySet)
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                // now we have a Flux<List<MyObject>>
                // and all MyObject in that list have 
                // the same name
                .filter(allObjectsWithSameName -> !allObjectsWithSameName.isEmpty())
                // now we sort all the lists in descending order
                // and return the first element
                // which is the one with the highest prio
                .map(allObjectsWithSameName -> {
                            allObjectsWithSameName.sort(new Comparator<MyObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
                                    return Integer.compare(o2.priority, o1.priority);
                                }
                            });
                            return allObjectsWithSameName.get(0);
                        }
                );

        myFlux.subscribe(result -> System.out.println("MyObject: " + result.toString()));
    }

    @Data
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public static class MyObject {
        final String name;
        final int priority;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MyObject: Example.MyObject(name=abc, priority=4)
MyObject: Example.MyObject(name=cde, priority=1)
```